# How do you stop people from editing a disabled inputbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, user-input

When a input textbox is disabled, you can not enter any values into the Inputbox.

However if you use google chrome and right click on the inputbox then click on inspect, you can change the values.

How do you stop people from editing a disabled inputbox?

Comment: I think the only way to stop this is to implement a server side checking when the form is submitted.

Comment: You can instruct clients to do this and that through your code, but there is **no way** you can *force* them to comply with your wishes. Anyone can send a HTTP request to your server scripts with any parameters they wish, regardless of what you want them to send. This is very important to be aware of if you want to write secure backends.

Comment: :: sigh :: remove the input box altogether. Problem solved. Or, it you want it more subtle, how about removing its `id` attribute, so it won't get posted.

Comment: @AnotherCode Ooh, those were the days. Sites that thoroughly checked the GET type postback they received, but always accepted all POST values, because they assumed nobody could fake a POST. Lovely.

Comment: Don't show the content as input but only as text

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The only thing you can (and **always** should) do is validate user's input on server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can stop people from changing its state and sending the data. There are two way you can do this

1. Do not display the `disabled` input at all. Just like what Zend_Form does.
2. Check the field when the form was submitted and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, the disabled input value won't be posted to server side. So if someone change the value using tools, the modified data will not be posted.

Comment: With the same tools `disabled` attribute can be removed as well

Comment: Yes, but if someone can change the value of a disabled control, they can also change the `disabled` attribute. And then it _will_ get posted.